# How to configure SQL table to allow insertion of empty string to datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, datetime

I have a SQL database and a table with the following field:

```
MustHaveDate datetime,
```

I am populating this table using an insert command which basically iterates over a data object creating parameters. There are a large number of parameters.

I do this in VBA by creating a SQL dictionary of all my values, for example:

```
m_SQLDictionary.Add "MustHaveDate", Array(m_MustHaveDate, adDate)
```

with the SQL tablename as the dictionary key and the value/datatype for use in the parameter as the data contained in the dictionary. `m_MustHaveDate` will either be "" or a "YYYY-MM-DD" format string.

I then can simply iterate through `m_SQLDictionary.keys()` to build all my parameters for a SQL query and the query itself (the sqlDict is m_SQLDictionary from above):

```
       'get data and create list of parameters
        normalResult = sqlDict(myKey)

        Dim dataType As Integer
        Dim dataVal
        dataType = CInt(normalResult(1))
        dataVal = normalResult(0)
        updateCommand.Parameters.Append updateCommand.CreateParameter(myKey, dataType, adParamInput, -1, dataVal)
```

This works great 99% of the time. However, occasionally I have an empty string for `m_MustHaveDate` and I am unable to successfully perform the SQL `INSERT` (gives this error: "Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation").

Is there a way to declare the field in SQL to not throw an error in this situation?

Comment: You have two options: insert `null` (use the VB value `Null` as the parameter value) instead of empty string, or convert your date column to text format (which will allow empty string). The first option is the way to go.

Comment: @TimWilliams interestingly, the reason I now have this problem is I previously had this column as a text format column.

Comment: If you're only storing dates there then using a date column is an improvement!  I wouldn't recommend switching back to text just to solve the null problem.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah. I guess I'll see if it's possible to have a VBA string "Null" or something passed as a parameter to a command as for an adDate (this doesn't seem promising, unfortunately).

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem unless the field is defined as "not null"...

Comment: @TimWilliams yet here we are :)  if I add a parameter as `adDate` and "" as a value it causes this error.

Comment: Empty string is not the same as null.  Try `Null` As the value (not the string "Null" - there's a defined value specifically for this case)

Comment: @TimWilliams both `Null` and `vbNullString` cause the same problem. I think I'm going to have to include some `<>0` and `<> ""` code to my logic when I create the parameters.

Comment: OK - "works for me", but I'm typically using Oracle and perhaps taking a different approach to creating and populating my parameters...  Are you using SQL server?

Comment: @TimWilliams I am using SQL Server 2005 yes. I also added the exact code I'm using to create the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Too much to put into a comment, so here's what works for me.  Typically using Oracle for this type of thing, but *should* map over sort-of...

I'm a bit lazy and tend to use Variant parameters (so I can use a generic procedure to run parameterized queries/updates)

A function to run a generic parameterised update (part of a larger class):

```
'Return true if OK, false if not
Public Function UpdateParameterized(sSQL, parameters) As Boolean
Dim cmd As ADODB.command, i As Integer
Dim bReturn As Boolean, param As Object

    If oConn.State <> adStateOpen Then Me.Connect
    If oRS.State = adStateOpen Then oRS.Close 'close RS if already open

    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    For i = 0 To UBound(parameters)
        Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("", adVariant, _
                          adParamInput, 0, parameters(i))
        cmd.parameters.Append param
    Next

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = oConn

    On Error Resume Next
    sLastError = ""

    cmd.Execute

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        sLastError = "Error running parameterized update: " & _
                      Err.Description
        Err.Clear
        bReturn = False
    Else
        bReturn = True
    End If

    UpdateParameterized = bReturn

End Function
```

Helper functions for checking whether to pass a value or Null as a parameter value:

```
Function NumberOrNull(v)
    NumberOrNull = IIf((IsNumeric(v) And Len(v) > 0), v, Null)
End Function

Function StringOrNull(v)
    StringOrNull = IIf(Len(v & "") > 0, v, Null)
End Function
```

Example useage:

```
 UpdateParameterized( "update tablename set t.field= ? where t.id = 1234 ", _
                      Array(StringOrNull(somevalue)) )
```

Comment: Hm, I'll have to try making it a variant - that seems like a nice way to avoid this problem if it works (as well as a nice way to obscure potential future problems, though)

Comment: hm, so with SQL Server 2008, making it an adVariant results with the error `Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to datetime is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.` (for both empty and valid date strings).